# Format file for BULK INSERT of scientific numbers

Tags: sql-server, formatting, ascii

The following ascii file with numbers in scientific notation:

```
   3.1182156e+01       1.2141212e+02       5.6468558e-01    
   3.1182060e+01       1.2141212e+02       5.4650307e-01    
   3.1181965e+01       1.2141212e+02       5.3390592e-01    
   3.1181870e+01       1.2141212e+02       5.2496111e-01    
   3.1181772e+01       1.2141212e+02       5.1364386e-01    
   3.1181677e+01       1.2141212e+02       5.0890839e-01    
   3.1181581e+01       1.2141212e+02       5.0689977e-01
```

should be BULK INSERTed to SQL server. [In Notepad++ i can see that there are 3 spaces infront of each number and always a tab behind the number like '___3.1181581e+01tab']. The actual ascii file is over 12GB and cannot be edited.

The target table is

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BIG_TEST](
    [lat] [float] NULL,
    [lon] [float] NULL,
    [img1] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

the BULK INSERT command is

```
BULK INSERT BIG_TEST FROM 'C:\test.txt' 
WITH(
FORMATFILE = 'C:\BIG_TEST.xml',
TABLOCK
)
```

I think the main problem is the format file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID =" 1 " xsi:type =" CharTerm " TERMINATOR = " \t" MAXLENGTH = " 16 " />
  <FIELD ID =" 2 " xsi:type =" CharTerm " TERMINATOR = " \t" MAXLENGTH = " 16 " />
  <FIELD ID =" 3 " xsi:type =" CharTerm " TERMINATOR = " \t" MAXLENGTH = " 16 " />
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
   <COLUMN SOURCE =" 1 " NAME =" lat " xsi:type =" SQLFLT8  "/>
   <COLUMN SOURCE =" 2 " NAME =" lon " xsi:type =" SQLFLT8  "/>
   <COLUMN SOURCE =" 3 " NAME =" img1 " xsi:type =" SQLFLT8  "/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

I have tried various combinations according to [this](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/piotr_rodak/archive/2009/05/17/bcp-and-numeric-data-field.aspx) and [this Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189327%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) website, but it seems i cannot figure it out by myself. The error message is:

```
Msg 4858, Level 16, State 1, Line 32
Line 4 in format file "C:\BIG_TEST.xml": bad value  CharTerm  for attribute "xsi:type".
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: this is not related to the error but imo in the sample data the 3rd field is not terminated by a tab but a cr and/or lf

Comment: I have found another way to export my data, reading ASCII is not needed anymore. @admin can I withdraw my question?